# mmap vs O_DIRECT for random reads (what are the buffers involved?)

Tags: c, file-io, buffer, hashtable, mmap

I am implementing a disk based hashtable supporting large amount of keys (26+ million). The value is deserialized. Reads are essentially random throughout the file, values are less than the page size, and I am optimising for SSDs. Safety/consistency are not such huge issues (performance matters).

My current solution involves using a `mmap()` file with `MADV_RANDOM | MADV_DONTNEED` set to disable prefetching by the kernel and only load data as needed on-demand.

I get the idea that the kernel reads from disk to memory buffer, and I deserialize from there.

What about `O_DIRECT`? If I call `read()`, I'm still copying into a buffer (which I deserialize from) so can I gain any advantage?

Where can I find more info on the buffers involved with a `mmap()` file and calling `read()` on a file opened with `O_DIRECT`?

I am not interested in read ahead or caching. It has nothing to offer for my use case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O_DIRECT is option for read/write operations, when data bypass system buffers, and copied directlty from your buffer to disk controller. For get advantages of O_DIRECT, need to 
comply some conditions - keep aligned by memory page buffer address and buffer size aligned by I/O block.

Anyway, if you use mmap, you do not use read/write. Moreover, after mmap, you can close file descriptor, and mapping will still works. So, O_DIRECT useless with mmap option.

What can I recommend for increase performance:

1. If your subsystem has many request for search missing key, you can create Bloom filter in the memory. Thereafter, you match your search key on Bloom filter http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter, and reject missing keys, without actual request to disk.
2. For conserve memory, use 2-level scheme, when bucket heads you keep in the mmap-ed memory, but buckets itself you read from file by pread().

Both options I implemented in the my autocomplete subsytem, you can see it online here: http://olegh.ftp.sh/autocomplete.html and estimate performance on the slow old computer - Celeron-300.